# Message Handler in Java - Flash socket server

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash

So I'm trying to do some research while on down time before starting a project.

[I'm following this tutorial](http://www.broculos.net/en/article/how-make-multi-client-flash-java-server) with a friend to try to make a flash based online game. I'm doing the flash side of the project and she's doing the java side. While looking this over I haven't been able to find a message handler on the java server code.

This makes sense as the tutorial is trying to be as simple and easy to understand as it can.

[Another tutorial I've read through (but am not using as it's server is handled by an outside party) uses a built in message handler that is unavailable to me.](http://playerio.com/documentation/tutorials/building-flash-multiplayer-games-tutorial/gamebasics)

So what I'm looking to know is how would one build a message handler that can receive messages with various numbers of parameters and how would you format the initial message in flash?

The transition in understanding from that PLAYER.IO tutorial into a proprietary system is a pretty huge leap so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first tutorial implements a server by simply creating a class that extends Thread. It starts a new instance of `PolicyServerConnection` on each client connection and this class is responsible for deserializing the data received from the client and serve the request. This is a very simple and low-level solution. In this case you need to define how client will send request to the server, how will it serialize the parameters and how server will interpret them.

You could instead use e.g. BlazeDs, that makes possible to export methods and parameters and provides the infrastructure to deserialize the request of the client and route it to the appropriate method with the parameters received.

Comment: Do you happen to have any resources i.e. tutorials that could explain this in more detail?

Comment: [Do you think this illustrates how we could use BlazeDS?](http://programmaremobile.blogspot.ca/2009/10/java-and-blazeds-by-example.html)

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought of. And this seems also a detailed 'how to start" tutorial: [Adobe's tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/blazeds_gettingstarted.html)

Comment: That definitely will be helpful. Do you happen to know of any BlazeDS resources that don't use FLEX?

Comment: BlazeDS is for integration Flex client with server-side. What do you mean by "any BlazeDS resources that don't use FLEX"?

Comment: I don't know anything about networking or the languages that support it. I guess I don't mean anything. I was just hoping for some simple ways to start out so you have something to work with in the early stages before you start getting things complex.

Comment: BlazeDS is a framework that let you connect your flex client to a java application server. With it you can export the methods of your service class on the serverside, so the client can use [Remote Objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/remoting/mxml/RemoteObject.html) to call server side.
Try to follow the steps in the tutorial from Adobe I have linked in a previous comment, it will allow you to see what is it really about, and probably help you get on track with the game.